# How to add javascript in a prestashop module

Tags: prestashop

Is it possible to integrate javascript in a module without a direct injection in the template smarty?

Comment: Solved ,

I added a Js file in my module directory (ex : mymodule/views/js/abo_front.js).
I created a Hook to the header to declare my js file in the header.


    public function install() 
    {
      return parent :: install() && $this->resetDb() 
      && $this->registerHook('header');
    
     }
    
     public function hookHeader($params)
     {
      $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'views/js/abo_front.js');
     }

Answer (score 11):

Solved ,

I added a Js file in my module directory (ex : mymodule/views/js/abo_front.js).
In my module class, I created a Hook to the header to declare my js file in the header.

```
public function install() 
{
        return parent :: install() && $this->resetDb() 
        && $this->registerHook('header');

    }

    public function hookHeader($params)
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'views/js/abo_front.js');
    }
```