# how to load js files to prestashop in mobile version

Tags: mobile, prestashop

I would like to load some js files to prestashop module in mobile version, this problem occur only in mobile version, i have this code

```
 public function install() {
    return parent :: install()
    && $this->registerHook('displayCenterleftColumn') &&
```

$this->registerHook('Header');
    }

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{

        //Tools::addCSS(_PS_CSS_DIR_.'jquery.autocomplete.css');

    //Tools::addCSS(_PS_CSS_DIR_.'jquery.autocomplete.css');

        $this->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'front/css/param_product.css');
    //$this->context->controller->addCSS('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css');
     //$this->context->controller->addCSS(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."spinner/ui.spinner.css");
     //$this->context->controller->addJS("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js");

          $this->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_."blockcart/ajax-cart.js");
          $this->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/functions.js');
          $this->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/main.js');
$this->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/jquery.validate.js'); 
}
```

other question in header.tpl there's this code

```
{foreach from=$js_files item=js_uri}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_uri}"></script>
{/foreach}
```

Where can i set $js_files variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall your new module.

Second, put this code in your module:

```
function install() {
    if (!parent::install())
        return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('displayCenterleftColumn'))
        return false;
    if (!$this->registerHook('header'))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Third, install again your module.

Your problem is that is using 'Header' into install function, and it's a incorrect value. The value correct is 'header'.

Regards and good luck!

Comment: It does'nt solve the problem, i would  like it work in mobile, in computer version there's no problem.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806136/how-to-add-javascript-in-a-prestashop-module. Verify if all js and css files are loading in page. It's possible that paths are diferents into the theme.

Comment: the js and css load  must be injected in hookdisplayMobileHeader in the install file of the module to work in mobile thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem, i added a displayhookMobile function in my module install file

```
public function     hookdisplayMobileHeader($params) in which i assigned my js and css file

 public function    hookdisplayMobileHeader($params){
$this->context->controller->addJS(_MODULE_DIR_."blockcart/ajax-cart.js");
$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/functions.js');
$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/main.js');
$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'front/js/jquery.validate.js'); 
}
```